# What is the difference between a 1st and 2nd Order Digital Filter

Tags: filter, control, transfer-function, digital-filter

I was just curious as to the differences between the two order filters?

**How I created these discrete filters for references**

- Designed in Continuous first then converted into Discrete
- Using Tustin's method as I just want to convert the plant from continuous to discrete
- Fc = 20kHZ
- Used Prep warping nyquist frequency = 20kHZ (Sampling at Ts = 0.000025/40kHz)

**Filter 1: 2nd Order Butterworth filter Analog**

[image]

**Filter 1A: 2nd Order Butterworth Filter Discrete**

[image]

**Filter 2: 1st Order RC Filter Discrete**

[image]

As you can see in **Filter 1A** I was shocked to see that "Brick-wall" response and was curious to see what if I used a lower order filter.

In **Filter 2** you can see a similar result. The only difference I can tell is that magnitude (dB). The 1st Order filter has a flatter pass band then the 2nd Order Butterworth Filter.

Is there any advantage in using a higher order filter when it comes to discrete? Why in discrete the "Brick-Wall" response is much more apparent now when its only a 2nd Order.

Let me know if I even approached this correctly has I haven't dont discrete in a long time, so I wouldn't be surprise if something went wrong.

**Bonus question, why when I try to do a step response for both filters I get this:**

[image]

Another question that came to mind: Could we use the Sampling time to essentially change the Cut off frequency then?

EDIT: Looks like my Sampling times are wrong no idea what I am doing anymore. How do you know which Sampling Time is suitable for you? Or is that the trade off sacrifice how close it looks to the continuous for sampling times

Code:

```
%% -- Low Pass Filter (LPF) -- %%
R1 = 15000;
R2 = 9100;
C1 = 0.001*10^-6;
C2 = 470*10^-12;

LPF_A = ((1)/(C2*R1*s + C2*R2*s + C1*C2*R1*R2*s^2 + 1));
opt = c2dOptions('Method','tustin','PrewarpFrequency',125663.706);
LPF_D = c2d(LPF_A,0.000025,opt);
```

Comment: Since your transfer function doesn't look like a low pass filter and your step response is an increasing oscillating function, it seems that something went wrong in how you designed the filter.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying. I can confirm its the right transfer function. More importantly if I increase the Sampling rate it now shows a proper step response.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? I can't make out the sampling frequency, is it 40kHz? Nyquist should be strictly greater than fc, not greater than or equal. Then Ts is 25us/40kHz=62.5ns? It's confusing.

Comment: Yeah of course. Ill put in the main post. @aconcernedcitizen The code is there now

Comment: @user1850479 The analog filter clearly has a 2nd order magnitude/phase response, and a 2nd order polynomial at the denominator which, when calculated gives a perfectly good Laplace transfer function. The problem could not have been in the design, but in the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Matlab, but looking at their online help for [c2d](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html) and [c2dOptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2doptions.html):

> 'FractDelayApproxOrder'
>
> Maximum order of the Thiran filter used to approximate fractional delays in the 'tustin' and 'matched' methods. Takes integer values. A value of 0 means that c2d rounds fractional delays to the nearest integer multiple of the sample time.

So, unless you have a need for a delay, you should set that to zero. The code should look like this:

```
opt = c2dOptions('Method', 'tustin', 'PrewarpFrequency', 0);
f0 = 80000;
opt = c2dOptions('Method', 'tustin', 'PrewarpFrequency', f0);
LPF_D = c2d(LPF_A, 1/f0, opt);
```

Let me know if this does it for you (I really don't have Matlab).

---

Re-read the online description, it looks like `'tustin'` allows the `'PrewarpFrequency'`, so then you should match that with the `c2d()`, see updated code.

Comment: Well, in C2D options it does set FractDelayApproxOrder to 0

Comment: @Pllsz See the updated answer.

Comment: Just checked it. The Fc (Cut off Freq) is no where near the 20kHZ mark. Compare to the original code

Comment: The Nyquist frequency, f0/2, needs to be greater than fc, so 40kHz is way too low. Try 80kHz. Just realized I copy-pasted your values, without changing f0, as mentioned in the comments above. But if you really aim for a fairly good match in  magnitude, f0 should be ~10 times more, if you can afford it.

Comment: ahhh I see, that would make sense. So essentially the higher sample freq will allow the discrete function to look more like the continuous at the trade off for more computing power? Another question is why when I just have a really fast Sample time (0.000000001) I dont need to Pre-Warp?

Comment: @Pllsz If you plot, side by side, an analog filter and its IIR bilinear version with f0>20*fc, you'll see that the "tangent effect" is only felt towards the Nyquist frequency, leaving the lower ferquency band very close to the analog filter's. Prewarping math is based on a tangent (among others), so, the larger the bandwidth, the lesser effect it has away of Nyquist, but also the more power of processing is needed. As always, there's a price to pay, and something to gain, with the choice being on the designer.

Comment: That make sense thank you. So my question is if my discrete cut off frequency is where I want it but doesn't exactly replicate the continuous would I consider that complete? With your code above should it be for sampling time = 125e-7 giving you Fs = 80kHZ Fnquist = 40kHZ I think your code is if f0 = 20kHz Ts = 0.5e-4 Fs = 20kHZ Fnquist = 10kHZ

Comment: I modified the answer in the meantime and set f0=80kHz (f0 was 40kHz, Ts=25us, as you posted in your code). And, yes, the bilinear transform is supposed to guarantee bandwidth accuracy provided a proper sampling frequency is chosen. Besides, for a lowpass, the high attenuation towards Nyquist can only be beneficial... as long as aliasing isn't a problem.

Comment: Wouldnt f0 be my critical frequency for example this filter had a 20kHZ cut off would I want f0 = 20kHZ? Also the function takes in Rad/s I believe not Frequency

Comment: The sampling time of 80kHZ make sense, but I think choosing the f0 doesnt

Comment: Maybe you're used to a different notation? `f0` is the sampling frequency. Some use `fs`, and it's not necessary critical unless your design requirements impose it. If `fc` was strict, that would be critical. Something always is, and the rest needs to be adapted. In your case, you know what you're using the filter for, so it's up to you to declare what is critical and what is not. But it looks like you're really just throwing a dice: "maybe I'll use 40kHz, maybe 80, ...". My suggestion would be to first write down the requirements. Then, see *how* to build the filter to get to that.

Comment: So essentially the Pre-Warp frequency is the sampling Frequency?

Comment: I don't know how to put this delicately, but it really looks like you lack some basic notions, so maybe it would be better to first read about signals and systems first, before digging into filter design teritory? [This](http://www.dspguide.com/) is a free online book. Otherwise this discussion will stretch at every step of an explanation with "but what is that?".

Comment: Yeah fair! Appreciate the help ! Thank you

Comment: There is also a lecture series on [Signals and Systems](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/).