# Why is the prewarping not working as it should?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, matlab, digital-filter

Just playing around with the 'c2d' command from matlab and trying to convert a continuous 2nd - order lowpass Butterworth function to a digital one which has the specs of Fc = 20e3Hz and Fs = 44.410e3Hz.

When I apply the pre-warping frequency parameter of 20e3Hz, it doesn't close to mimicking the continuous function.

Is there a reason why this is occurring? Does the prewarping have a limitation of how much it can "pre-warp" or am I doing something wrong? Maybe that's the intended output?

Legends:

- LP = Continuous TF
- LP_D = Discrete TF

[image]

Code:

```
s = tf('s');

LP = 15587249629.803/(s^2+176556.77655678*s+15587249629.803);
LP_D = c2d(LP,1/44.410e3,['Method','tustin','prewarpFrequency',125663.706]);
```

UPDATE: With a higher FS = 96e3Hz from 44.410e3Hz with no pre warping:

[image]

UPDATE2: Comparing with and without prewarping on two different Fs (44.410kHz and 96kHz) using a 3rd order Butterworth filter lowpass

Cutoff frequencies:

- LP = 1.25e5 rad/s
- LP_D_44kHz = 6.70e4 rad/s
- LP_D_96kHz = 1.10e5 rad/s

**With pre-warping:**

[image]

Cutoff frequencies:

- LP = 1.25e5 rad/s
- LP_D_44kHz = 8.59e4 rad/s
- LP_D_96kHz = 1.13e5 rad/s

**Without pre-warping:**
[image]

UPDATE 3: Doing some research I might have an idea. Just a gut feeling.

I found 2 resources that converted an analog Butterworth into a discrete one using the Tustin method with prewarping and it worked for them.

I noticed they created the Butterworth filter completely different from the way I did it. I made mine based on the Sallen-Key configuration and just found the transfer function, could that be it? For some reason the Sallen-Key way doesn,'t like the prewarping?

Resources [HERE](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Mathematics/Systems-and-Control-Theory/Digital-filters/Discretization/Discretization-of-a-fourth-order-Butterworth-filter.html) and [HERE](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Esjrob/Teaching/SP/l6.pdf)

I also noticed when using a notch filter with the same sampling frequency (44.410kHz) and prewarping it works perfectly. Why when doing low pass filters it doesn't like it that much?

UPDATE 4: Could be the warping is just to nonlinear for it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113349/discussion-on-question-by-leoc-why-is-the-prewarping-not-working-as-it-should).

Comment: Update main post. Found new findings

Comment: You can also post this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thats what I am actually doing right now

Comment: @Leoc If you read through [the comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487737/what-is-the-difference-between-a-1st-and-2nd-order-digital-filter#comment1241398_487847), you'd have seen that I said your corner frequency is too close to Nyquist. Same thing here. The prewarping implies a `tan()`, and that's the effect you're seeing here. Also, when replying to someone, use `@<tab>` to select the name, otherwise the other person might not get noticed.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, I am aware of the tagging, it sometimes works sometimes doesnt. I see So essentially whats going on here that the frequency is way too close to the Nyquist and its linearities are too much for the warping to handle? Did I understand that correctly? So I either have to increase the Fs or perhaps try FIR?

Comment: "*I am aware of the tagging*" -- it never hurts to be cautious. And, yes, that's why it all happens. If you want a nice, clean waveform at the end, you need some 10x f0 compared to the highest fp. Same with frequency-domain. Never forget that bilinear transform implies a mapping of a linear domain, `s`, to a strongly nonlinear domain, `z`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Assuming "Fp" = Fnyq or Fs hahah. Thank you good sir for verifying with me and yes I do agree being cautious never hurts thanks for the reminder

Comment: @Leoc I meant `fp` = passband (corner) frequency and `f0` = sampling frequency.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen understood, thanks captain